# Trying to implement a simple/efficient combinations function in MATLAB

Tags: matrix, matlab, efficiency, combinatorics

So, recently, I have found myself in the position of having to implement a combinations function in MATLAB. What I mean by this is the following: I simply need to list all possible combinations for an ${m \choose n}$ problem.

More concretely, lets say I am given an $m=4$ length vector, where its indicies increase from $1$ to $m$, (e.g. $[1, 2, 3, 4]$). Let us also say that in this example, $n = 2$. Thus, I want to find all ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ possible combinations, and I would like the routine to therefore spit out: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\1  & 3 \\ 1&4 \\2&3\\2&4\\3&4 \end{bmatrix} $$.

(The reason I need a list like that is because those numbers are going to be used as indicies of another matrix, but thats not important). Now, Ive googled around, and MATLAB has a function to do this, but I do not have it, as I dont have the stats toolbox. Be that as it may, I suppose I could sook something up, but I do not think that it would be too efficient, and worse still, it might not be generalizable for any $m$ or $n$.

I therefore would not mind writing my own routine, if it is not too involved, but I would like some help as to how this can be accomplished. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an implementation in [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). The function is, as in Matlab, called `nchoosek`. Documentation is [here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/nchoosek.html). For the theory behind this type of algorithms, you can consult section 7.2.1 of Volume 4A of The Art Of Computer Programming by Donald Knuth.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I have nchoosek. I am trying to make a list of numbers, as that matrix shows, not figure out how to compute nchoosek.

Comment: @Bateekha: aren't you looking for this: ´nchoosek (1:3, 2)´, i.e. give a vector to nchoosek as first argument so that it returns a list of all combinations?

Comment: @Bateekha: in your original post, you mention "MATLAB has a function to do this, but I do not have it"... That's why I pointed you to Octave.

Comment: >< You are correct. That is exactly what I need. ><

Comment: I guess I do not understand how this works...is there a simple 'way' of going about computing it? (I am looking at the function).

Comment: @Bateekha: have a look [here](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/5165-09/GenCombObj.pdf) and section 7.2.1 of The Art Of Computer Programming (Volume 4A) by Donald Knuth.